# как из одной таблицы вставить только измененные строки в другую таблицу

Tags: mysql

Есть две абсолютно одинаковые таблицы.
Таблица №1 содержит инфу по сотрудникам(id,ФИО,год рождения,..)
Таблица №2 полностью дублирует Таблицу№1

вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при изменении любого поля в Таблице №1, например, у сотрудника изменилась фамилия, в Таблицу №2 передалась обновленная строка по этому сотруднику?

Comment: Повесить триггер. А в целом в чём смысл дубля таблицы?

Comment: Таблица №1 транкейтится раз в сутки и наполняется с такой же периодичностью из внешних источников, именно для того и нужна Таблица№2 в которой будет всегда актуальная информация.
как это реализовать пока не очень понимаю, возможно есть какие-либо примеры структуры?

Comment: Гм... то есть первая чистится в ноль, а вторая - нет? и во второй есть любая запись, даже если она вчера была, а в сегодняшнем массиве данных таблицы 1 этой записи нет?

Comment: верно, Таблица2 не очищается.
не может быть такого,что в Таблице2 будет больше данных чем в Таблице1, потому как в Таблицу1 каждый день приходит вся информация по сотрудниками(по уволенным тоже, но с меткой об увольнении), а вот в Таблицу2 необходимо передавать только измененные данные по сотруднику ну или добавлять новую строку,если это новый сотрудник...

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что изменения должны переноситься в другую таблицу мгновенно, тогда решение - триггер.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `users_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `users1` FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE `users2`
SET `first_name` = NEW.`first_name`,
`last_name` = NEW.`last_name`
WHERE `id` = NEW.`id`
```

Этот триггер выполняет запрос `update` в таблицу `users2` после запроса `update` на таблицу `users1`.

Если вы так же хотите копировать данные при insert запросах, тогда нужно создать будет еще один триггер.